# How to manipulate html (or javascript) using python to scrape data entries

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to scrape university academic rankings from [this site](https://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/arwu/2020) using beautifulsoup in Python. Currently, I am able to grab the first 30 entries with no problem, however, the remaining entries require that I click for the next page each time. There is no option to show all entries.

When I click through the pages of entries the URL does not change so I imagine that these entries are being manipulated by javascript (?), however, when I inspect the source code I cannot find ways to manipulate this. *Admittedly, I am an amateur here.*

How can I use python to manipulate this webpage; either to show all entries or to loop through each page to extract the complete data set?

**UPDATE - Solution**

Thanks to the link provided by @j_carlson I was able to work out my solution:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/arwu/2021')
for page in range(npages+1)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # Extract what I want here
    next_button_class = 'ant-pagination-next'
    driver.find_element_by_class_name(next_button_class).click()
```

Which simply uses selenium to 'click' the next page button whose class is 'ant-pagination-next' (I found this by using chrome's inspect element function) and then loop through each page, extracting the data I want each time.

Comment: See if this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161330/how-to-go-to-next-page-using-beautiful-soup

Comment: Please add some code that show your effort and approach

Comment: Thanks @j__carlson . That link led me to be able to resolve my issue. I'm adding the end-result to my initial question.